# How to prepare environment variables with init containers in a Kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

I try to prepare environment variables with an init container, such that these can be used in the "actual" container. Here is the essential code I used:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  replicas: 1  # You can adjust the number of replicas as needed
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo here && echo $MY_VARIABLE && sleep 3600']
      initContainers:
      - name: init-myservice
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'export MY_VARIABLE="some_value" && sleep 1']
```

However, the main container does not recognize the variable I create in the initContainer.

Could you help me how to make that possible?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Where does the actual value come from; why does it need to be set at run time?  Could you set it as an `ENV` value in your Dockerfile, or via deploy-time configuration using a tool like Kustomize or Helm?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to use Pgbouncer, but I do not like that I would have to use secrets. Instead I would like to use vault, prepare the secrets then, such that I can use them in the actual pgbouncer container.

Comment: initContainers cannot directly set environment variables for main containers, better to use ConfigMap/Secret.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define a shared volume for init container and the main container. In the init container create a file in the shared volume and include all required environment variables as key-value pairs.

Then in the main container export the key-value pairs from the file in shared volume ( source /shared-vol/myVars.txt ) and run the startup script.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. Could you share an example, such that I have an idea how to solve it?